# postgresql: store result of sql query in variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to store the result of a sql query, which should be a single date, in a variable. I'm doing this because I plan to reuse the variable several times throughout the rest of the script. I've tried the following:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  date_ordered date;
BEGIN
  date_ordered := SELECT MIN(event_date) FROM event;
END;
$$
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error at `SELECT`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the query in parenthesis.

```
...
date_ordered := (SELECT MIN(event_date) FROM event);
...
```

Or use `SELECT ... INTO`.

```
...
SELECT MIN(event_date) INTO date_ordered FROM event;
...
```